# ¿Cómo hacer un aviso intermitente?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Necesito hacer un aviso de forma parpadeante o intermitente. El código que tengo consiste en hacer **clic** en un botón para luego ver un aviso que nos dice:

> **¡Tenga Precaución!**.

Estoy intentando con el siguiente código:

```js
caution = function(){
 /*con esto solo hago aparecer un párrafo que estaba escondido*/
  displayP.style.display="block";
 /*aquí es donde no se que hacer necesito saber una propiedad que me permita 
 hacer que el aviso "tenga precaución" salga de forma intermitente*/
};
/*creo una variable que sea la equivalente al párrafo id "p-btn"*/
var boton = document.getElementById("p-btn");
/*agrego un evento al parrafo que tiene la propiedad de boton*/
boton.addEventListener("click", caution);
 /*creo una variable que sea la equivalente al párrafo id "precaución"*/
var displayP = document.getElementById("precaucion");
```

```css
#p-btn{background:rgba(204,0,51,0.4);padding: 5px;width: 70px;box-shadow: -2px 2px 3px #ac0033;color: white;}
#p-btn:active{box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #890033;color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);}
#precaucion{text-transform: capitalize; color: red; display: none;}
```

```html
<div>
 <p id="p-btn">click aquí</p>
 <p id="precaucion">¡Tenga precaucion!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No es necesario utilizar **Javascript** para esto, intenta con el siguiente código:

```js
document.getElementById("p-btn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  document.getElementById("precaucion").style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#p-btn {
  background: rgba(204,0,51,0.4);
  padding: 5px;
  width: 70px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 3px #ac0033;
  color: white;
 }
#p-btn:active {
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #890033;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

#precaucion {
  text-transform: capitalize;  
  background: red;
  animation: alerta 1.5s linear 100ms infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes alerta {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    25% {opacity: 1;}
    75% {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
} 

@keyframes alerta {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    25% {opacity: 1;}
    75% {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<p id="p-btn">Pulse aquí</p>
<p id="precaucion">¡Tenga precaución!</p>
```

Básicamente eché mano de las [**transiciones CSS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Usando_animaciones_CSS).

Comment: Decía que no era necesario js, me refería específicamente a la "animación" del Div. Existen diferentes formas de hacerlo... este es solo un ejemplo....

Comment: ¿Me permites una mejora en la animación? En vez de usar dos puntos, `from` y `to`, insertar un tercero intermedio (en `50%`) para que la animación sea más suave.

Comment: Todo tuyo!!! cualquier mejora le viene bien al OP. Gracias.

Comment: Hecho. He eliminado el `<div>` adicional que agregaste (no es necesario), cambiado el nombre de la animación por `alerta` para que el OP entienda su uso (y no lo confunda con un atributo CSS normal) y modificada la animación para que permanezca más tiempo visible el texto y, además, he corregido el orden correcto de la versión corta (es [`name`, `duration`, `timing-function`, `delay`, `iteration-count`, etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/animation)).

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho. Aunque en mi plataforma de netbeans me arroja un error pero aún así se ejecuta el código.

Comment: Comparte el mensaje de error y lo vemos. Ten presente que puede que no sea "netbeans" como tal sino un tema de compatibilidad del browser.